# Application not connecting to SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I work for an ambulance company and they have recently invested in these tablets that go on the trucks and all patient data for the incident can be recorded onto it using a software called MobiMed by Octivus, problem is since resetting the software to ensure any previous patient data is erased, I have reinstalled Mobimed and the software that came with it (We were only given the msi's already stored on the tablets) to find that it gets stuck when trying to launch on "connecting to database 127.0.0.1:1791" and it just keeps counting up. All the logs say are: "Waiting for DBI/DBO to be ready"

It's running SQL Server 2008 R2 and it hasn't been modified from when we brought it. I've only uninstalled the software but after searching REGEDIT I can't find anything to do with usernames and the developers of the software aren't replying.

Any solutions to where i should even start? I haven't ventured into SQL Server before and it there's no guides for the software online...

[image: MobiMed]

[image: RegEdit]

[image: SQL Properties]

[image: MSI Folder]

[image: DBO software folder?]

EDIT - showing ports and msi config info.

[image: SQL Server port]

[image: Mobimed port]

[image: Mobimed msi]

[image: DBO Config msi]

[image: DB Interface config msi]

This all happened after i deleted the settings in regedit as it kept recreating the old settings cache, thank you for your help!

Comment: 127.0.0.1 means the local host, usually that tablet. That sounds like a configuration issue, unless the database is actually on the device itself. If not, that IP address should point to your database server.

Comment: You may need to make sure MSSQL is running on the tablet.

Comment: A few thoughts. You said it's using SQL Server 2008 R2, but your screen-shots show SQL Server Express. Was 2008 R2 removed during the uninstall, and perhaps didn't get reinstalled? Also, the default port for SQL Server is 1433. Since MobiMed is connecting using port 1791, SQL Server must be configured to listen on that port. Search for MobiMed and port 1791, and SQL Server listen port 1791. You should find help understanding how ports are used to control communication between the application and database.

Comment: You can run a command from an elevated command prompt to see what port SQL server is listening on. The command is `netstat -n -b -a`.  The output will show a lot of things. Look for the `ip_address:port` in the first column just about the `sqlservr.exe` process. I will write an answer so you can see what I'm talking about, even though it really isn't an answer -- it's just a troubleshooting step.

Comment: Ugh. Installing to the root of the C:\ drive rather than Program Files is not a sign of well-written software.

Comment: @JamesL Express Edition is one edition of Sql Server 2008 R2. They are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but I couldn't include this level of detail in comments.  So, here is an answer that will perhaps help you as you continue to troubleshoot.

If you can open an elevated command window (e.g., "Start | cmd | right+click | Run as administrator"), then you can run the following command to find the port on which SQL Server is listening:

`netstat -n -b -a`

The output will look something like this:

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [sqlservr.exe]
```

I use SQL Server 2008 R2.  The name of the process is `sqlservr.exe`, and you can see it is listening on port `1433`.  You should look for something similar on your tablet.  I'm not sure if the `exe` name for SQL Server Express is also `sqlservr.exe`.  So yours may be slightly different.

Make sure to find the line where the state is `LISTENING`, which is just above the `exe` name for SQL Server Express.

Whatever port SQL Server is listening on is the port that MobiMed should connect to.  You should be able to either configure SQL Server or MobiMed so that the ports match...

I would think the installer would have taken care of the port assignment for both SQL Server and MobiMed.  Perhaps there is another `.msi` package that should be installed?

Comment: The exe for SQL Express is also `sqlservr.exe`.

Comment: @James-l I looked through the ports to find sqlservr.exe listening in on port 49176 if its the line just above the exe name and not below) and i saw Mobimed and one of the other MSI's using port 4711, just to add some info to the msi's, one is the database interface whilst the DBO installs the premade Database into the local server on the tablet. I'll add the screenshots of everything into my question.

Comment: @J.Mordaunt - Several thoughts: Is the text to the right of the `mmm.exe` and `ortivus.exe` processes `Established` or `Listening`? The IP:PORT for a process is just **above** the exe name.  It is odd that SQL Server is listening on port 49167. You might try typing the port SQL Server is listening on (49167) on the `Enter portnumber for DBI server (1797)` line of the `MMM Configuration` dialog. Without knowing exactly how all the pieces communicate with each other, I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do, but it's worth trying. You can always set it back if it doesn't work.

Comment: I changed the port with hope but it just ticked up in time like before, the fact that the database was unchanged and before cleared regedit it all worked with that port leaves me a bit stumped.Maybe I should try completely uninstalling SQL and All the msi's? And i know it's local host though could it be a firewall issue? Windows action centre says that the firewall cannot be turned on due to a service error so maybe that's the issue? Though i set up a test setup with my laptop and it was stuck on connecting to database but i hadn't changed the port to the SQL servers.

Comment: @J.Mordaunt - Could be a Windows firewall issue, could be the syntax of 'database instance', could be antivirus/firewall blocking various parts of MobiMed from communicating with each other, etc., etc. Sorry I wasn't able to help you more. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I guess your Server Name in Ortivus DBO Installation is wrong.
Replace ORTIVUS with MEDI-TAB\ORTIVUS